# What triggers the Ruby warning about ambiguous first argument?

Tags: ruby, warnings

In Ruby 1.9.1, if you do

```
$VERBOSE = true
puts /m/ , 42.to_s
```

or if I do

```
$VERBOSE = true
puts /m/ , "42"
```

You get the warning

```
warning: ambiguous first argument; put parentheses or even spaces
```

But I don't get it if I do

```
$VERBOSE = true
puts "m" , 42.to_s
```

or

```
$VERBOSE = true
puts(/m/, 42.to_s)
```

So what specifically triggers this warning? And what more spaces could I have added to the original expression?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "problem" is that `/` could signify division or a regular expression. The message is generic; the parser doesn't necessarily mean that spaces would have helped a given specific expression.